# ¿Cómo puedo puedo obtener un número aleatorio en un rango aleatorio máximo?

Tags: python, random

Estoy tratando de obtener un rango aleatorio de por ejemplo, un número random para que se pueda generar automáticamente dicho número aleatorio con una longitud aleatoria máxima.

Mi código:

```
from random import randint

num1,num2,num3=randint(1, 20), randint(1, 20) #(Aquí está mi inquietud)
```

Me gustaría implementar algo así:

```
alm=[]
for i in range(1, 4):
    alm.append(randint(1,30))

print(alm)
```

Y añadirlo al resto de código

```
def mcd(n1,n2):
    if n1<n2:
        i=n1
    else:
        i=n2
    while not (n1 % i == 0 and n2 % i == 0):
        i -= 1
    else:
        return i

a=int(input('Valor a: ')) #Esto se puede sustituir por los valores de las longitudes random
b=int(input('Valor b: ')) #Esto se puede sustituir por los valores de las longitudes random

print(mcd(a, b))
mcd_result=(mcd(a, b))

mcm=((a*b)//(mcd_result))
print(mcm)
```

¿Cómo evito poner num1, num2, num3, etc., y definir una longitud random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en la ultima pregunta que haces, existe una forma, así es. Simplemente usa tu código para generar la lista de numeros aleatorios y crea un rango de longitud aleatoria así:

```
import random

alm=[]

max_list_width = 10

for i in range(random.randint(0,max_list_width)):
    alm.append(random.randint(1,30))

print(alm)
```

Este código puede devolver una lista vacía. Si quieres una cantidad minima (no aleatoria) de items en la lista, cambia el `0` de `range(random.randint(0,max_list_width))` al valor que quieras.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona correctamente. ¿Existe alguna forma de evaluar la cantidad de números de la lista en la función `mcd` teniendo en cuenta que son aleatorios?

Comment: hola @UlisesAntonioChávez ! La mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es votando la pregunta de forma positiva, y si crees que es la mejor respuesta, por que no marcandola como "respuesta correcta", esta es la mejor forma de dar las gracias y recompensar a Dante por su esfuerzo.

Comment: Por otro lado las preguntas han de ser "modulares", es decir, si tienes otra duda en este caso con tu función `mcd` lo mejor es crear una pregunta distinta. Espero haberte sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy facil

```
print (random.randrange(50,100))
```

De esta forma sacas un numero aleatorio entre 50 a 100

```
print (random.randrange(50,100))
```

De esta forma lo que hace es sacar un numero aleatorio entre dos números y además con un "delimitador" este te sacara un numero aleatorio de 5 en 5.

Comment: Tomando en cuenta eso, ¿cómo modifico la función `def mcd(n1,n2):` añadiendo el randint?

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez Para que usas es función ? No entiendo muy bine el codigo

Comment: Estoy haciendo un máximo común divisor tomando en cuenta todas las posibilidades hasta dar con dos números que coincidan y me arroje el mcd. Pero solo trabajo con dos números, en este caso trato de añadir más de dos  números aleatorios y me permita evaluarlos desde la función

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez has intentado hacer dos for?

Comment: Sí lo planteé, pero sinceramente no se me ocurre cómo implementarlo

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez Si quieres puedo ayudarte mas directo, dime por donde podemos hablar y te ayudo

Comment: Prefería hacerlo par aquí, pues desconozco si a alguien le pueda servir algún día esta información, planteando mi inquietud puede que sea la respuesta de alguien más en algún futuro. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Usando numpy, que es una librería muy usada para cálculo numérico, puedes usar su módulo random.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randint(low=2, high=4, size=8)
```

**Salida** `array([3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5])`

Tenemos tres parámetros:

- `low`: indicamos el número mínimo
- `high`: indicamos el número máximo
- `size`: indicamos el tamaño que queremos, en este caso ocho números.